# React Apollo's MockedProvider mock refetch() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, graphql, react-apollo

Using MockedProvider we can mock the output which is pretty straight, e.g.

```
let mocks = [{
    request: { query: DATA_QUERY, variables: {...} }
    result: {
        data: {...},
        refetch: () => console.log('refetch mocked') 
    }
}]
<MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
    <ComponentToTest />
</MockedProvider>
```

This gives me successful mocked output when executing `DATA_QUERY`

```
<Query query={DATA_QUERY} variables={...} fetchPolicy='cache-and-network' >
      {({data, refetch}) => refetch()
</Query>
```

Which should log `refetch mocked` on the console which is not happening in my case. May be it is not the right way to mock the `refetch` function, is it? If not, is there any way to mock the `refetch` function using `MockedProvider`

Thanks in anticipation